# Does Boost.Log need multithreading support (`-lpthread`)?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost, boost-log

I was trying to use Boost.Log without multithreading for a while without success. Now I came accross this statement in "configuring an building the library":

> The logging library uses several other Boost libraries that require building too. These are [..], **Boost.Thread** [...]

Is it about building the boost library itself or about building *my* code?

Here is what I tried:

```
#define BOOST_LOG_NO_THREADS

#define BOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK
#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int main() { BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(trace) << "TRACE LOG"; }
```

I compiled it this way:

```
g++ test.c++ -lboost_log -lboost_log_setup
```

The first error:

```
undefined reference to `boost::log::v2_st::trivial::logger::get()'
```

And then 3/4 of my screen full of errors; I'll post them if needed.

If I compile using `-lpthread` and without the `BOOST_LOG_NO_THREADS` definition it compiles fine.

If I use `-lpthread` without removing `BOOST_LOG_NO_THREADS` then I get the same errors.
**Why?

Can I compile my code without multithreading support?**

Comment: Is `BOOST_LOG_NO_THREADS` a public & documented option?

Comment: Yes, it's the 4th in the list: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation/config.html

Comment: the description makes me think that you have to build the boost log library with `BOOST_LOG_NO_THREADS`

Comment: You mean that I need the library itself built without multithreading support? I'm on arch linux and have the packages `boost` and `boost-libs` installed. I'll try to build boost manually now.

Comment: yes, I think you have to build it manually